# Converting MM/YY String to Date in SQL Server Equivalent to Oracle's TO_DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, data-conversion

I'm seeking a SQL Server equivalent to the Oracle query that converts an MM/YY string into a date:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TRIM('08/05'), 'MM/YY') FROM DUAL
```

In Oracle, this query produces a result of `2005-08-01 00:00:00.000` from the input string `08/05`, appending the first day of the month (`01`) to the converted date.

I attempted to replicate this functionality in SQL Server using concatenation and conversion functions:

```
SELECT 
    ('01-' +
    LEFT('08/05', 2) + '-' + 
    RIGHT('08/05', 2)) AS ConvertedDate
FROM 
    dbo.TABLE
```

However, the conversion to date fails due to potential bad or incomplete data.

I'm looking for a more straightforward approach or a SQL Server function that provides similar functionality to Oracle's `TO_DATE` in converting an MM/YY string to a date while appending the first day of the month. Any guidance or SQL Server-specific solution for this date conversion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2005,8,1)`? Would be good to explain your use case better. Your question is vague.

Comment: Do you "have" to work with the literal string `08/05'`? If nothing else, learn from the mistakes of the last century; we don't need a 2.1K bug.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(date, '01/' + '08/05', 3)`  is an option.

Comment: 08/05 is an example of the strings in the field. It could be 02/99 or 12/23.

Comment: Probably safer to use `TRY_CONVERT` mind, @Zhorov, for when the OP inevitably has a value like `'13/01'` or `'12/999'`.

Comment: @John How do you know whether 99 is 1899, 1999, 2099...? You are on high risk to produce incorrect dates. Just use proper dates rather than this strange casting of strings.

Comment: @John, include the table and column names - `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, '01/' + MonthAndYearAsText, 3) FROM dbo.TABLE`.

Comment: @John don't use such non-date values. What you posted is a bad string both in Oracle and SQL Server. Any conversion will have to use some very risky assumptions. You can't even tell which part is the year or month. And even if you make an assumption, you can't tell what the century is. If you think that's extreme, just ask [Lloyd's, whose Y2K hacks failed spectacularly in 2020](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/). That wasn't the only crash in January 2020 either. Before COVID lockdowns such Y2K bugs were the major news in IT

Comment: I'm not sure `TRY_CONVERT` is a good idea. Text fields like that are guaranteed to contain bad values like `12/999` or  different formats like `12/1999`. When that happens, `CONVERT` will fail forcing people to fix the bad data and avoid real-world problems. `TRY_CONVERT` will return NULL and I'd bet people would just skip this instead of trying to fix the error

Comment: Thanks all, I know the field is a bad format, I'm stuck with it for the moment. Thanks again. The TRY_CONVERT works a treat.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is the Oracle TO_DATE any better than TRY_CONVERT in terms of its output?

Comment: `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/'+'08/05', 3)` the style number `3` represents `dd/mm/yy` so if you are confident the original data is mm/yy I would use this in preference to try_cast() which doesn't accept the style number as a parameter. (and note that SQL Server's default date sequence is the bizarre month day year preferred by just ~10% of the world's population).